# How to force reinstall iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I wanted to download simulator components (Xcode 6.2), but during progress my internet connection was lost. Xcode still shows I've already have installed 7.1 simulator. Do you know how to force reinstall iOS simulator? I've done following steps:

- Removed the 'Downloads' directory from ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
- Removed all the 7.1 devices from Window -> Devices

It doesn't work... I would appreciate any help!

[image]

Comment: This is not a programming related question and is therefore more suitable for superuser.com

Comment: Try deleting / moving out items from this folder: ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/

Comment: @FlavienVolken, I've also tried but don't have this folder on my Mac. Probably it was changed since some version of Xcode. I hope reinstalling Xcode from App Store would help

Comment: @jaaakub you should have it, it is probably a problem of escaping the spaces. Open the terminal, then ```open ~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/```

Comment: @Shishdem you are wrong. I recommend to read the [On-Top help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again. "We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers… software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

Comment: I ensured again and don't have the `iPhone Simulator` folder. That was the first place I was looking for - I'm also confused it's not present anymore (OS X Yosemite, iMac)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I experienced the same issue this morning. What solved it for me was entering this in terminal:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS\ 7.1.simruntime
```

Edit: Forgot `-r` flag

Be sure to add your devices back in the devices window.

Edit 2: Xcode 15 stores newer "add-on" runtimes in `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/`, with a format like `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Volumes/{name_build}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/{name version}.simruntime`

Comment: I've downloaded previous version of Xcode (6.0.1). After that, installing components from 7.1 was possible. And then, I added devices from Window -> Devices by clicking "+" button and select appropriate platform version. I also removed entire `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode` directory. Your solution is more straightforward, i will remember it next time. Thanks!

Comment: `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS\ 8.1.simruntime` "8.1" worked for me. Thanks @Adrum

Comment: Your answer is useful. But my problem is that Xcode 7.x tell me I installed iOS 8.3, however, there is no 8.3 in `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/`. Could you tell me how to repair it?

Comment: This method work well with Xcode 8, you must close and reopen Xcode to see Preferences-Components updated.

Comment: Can you stop posting that file path. It no longer exists in the later version of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage different versions of your simulators in XCode > Settings > Platforms:

[image]