# How to uninstall downloaded Xcode simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

How to uninstall one of the downloaded Xcode simulators?

My *iOS 7 Simulator* won't boot (`Unable to boot the iOS Simulator`). I want to completely reinstall it.

[image]

I tried:

- Deleting `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode`
- Deleting Xcode and downloading it again from the App Store.

But the iOS 7.1 Simulator remains installed. How to remove it?

---

Note that I also tried:

- Resetting the simulator content and settings.
- Deleting the simulator device and creating it again.

and it didn't fix my problem.

Comment: In Xcode 6 you can simply go to Menu > Window > Devices > Simulators and delete a simulator you don't need.

Comment: @NeonSamuel: I have already tried that and it didn't help (see second-to-last line on my question).

Comment: you have to remove them from /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes

Answer (score 639, accepted):

You can remove them from `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes` *(Not `~/Library`!)*:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Yeah, this allowed me to delete and reinstall the simulator runtime, so thanks for that. Unfortunately it didn't fix my problem, I still get the `Unable to boot the iOS Simulator` message when trying to launch the 7.1 one.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29076171/how-to-force-reinstall-ios-simulator/29080441#29080441

Comment: Your answer is useful. But my problem is that Xcode 7.x tells me I installed iOS 8.3, however, there is no 8.3 in `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/`. Could you tell me how to repair it?

Comment: @DawnSong You need to first of delete those unuseful simulator remove and download simulator .dmg from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

Comment: I don't have Profiles folder. I use Xcode 7.1. Is something wrong with me? :)

Comment: @kiedysktos Look in /Library, not ~/Library

Comment: in /Library I don't have Developer folder, and in ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator there is no Profiles. But anyway my issues with simulator were solved by simple system restart

Comment: If you do not see the Profiles folder: http://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/quickly-showhide-hidden-files-mac-os-x-mavericks/

Comment: I do not have a directory `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/`, but I do have some significantly large folders in `Xcode-App-Bundle/Contents/Developer/Platforms`, that look like they could be the simulator runtimes. Their names end in `.platform` though, not `.simruntime`. Maybe Apple has moved where the files are? (I am running Xcode beta 8.3, I do not know for how long this would have been like this)

Comment: Folder doesn't exists on MacOS 11.3 and xCode 9.4

Comment: @PeterCullen, yup, seems they have changed it :-(  --- if anyone knows please feel free to update the answer.

Comment: My list of simulators showed nothing, no simulators, just "Generic iOS Device".  I deleted everything from the /Runtimes path as suggested and freed up over 20GB of space on disk. Then ran `xcrun simctl delete unavailable`. Now all my simulators repopulated in the "Devices & Simulators -> Simulators tab as well as the simulators list at the Run button. It seems that the iOS 12 simulators are hiding elsewhere as a `Run` will start a simulator but the simulator still never fully boots... back to original problem: "Failed to initiate service connection to simulator"

Comment: it works on Xcode 9.4.

Answer (score 110):

**NOTE**: This will only remove a device configuration from the Xcode devices list. To remove the simulator files from your hard drive see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30940055/2108547).

For Xcode 7 just use Window \ Devices menu in Xcode:

[image: Devices menu]

Then select emulator to delete in the list on the left side and right click on it.
Here is Delete option:
[image]

That's all.

Comment: finally a sane solution!

Comment: This will only remove a device configuration. The question was about removing a simulator (which has devices associated to it.) To remove the simulator as a whole, the version runtime needs to be removed. Xcode will remove the devices automatically on next app start for the removed runtime. See the answer from @NimitParekh above for way to do this.

Comment: What you do is just the simulator device, which are located in `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/`, and can be recreated as you said with almost no effort. However, any iOS simulator runtime is sizable, for example, 1.49G, which is located in `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes`.

Comment: This is wrong ... it's a configuration, not the simulator ..

Comment: @CTiPKA solution worked only partially for me (simulators disappeared from Xcode, but the app size itself stayed the same). In order permanently delete them just run `xcrun simctl delete unavailable`

Answer (score 97):

Run this command in terminal to remove simulators that can't be accessed from the current version of Xcode in use.

`xcrun simctl delete unavailable`

Also if you're looking to reclaim simulator related space [Michael Tsai](https://twitter.com/mjtsai/status/1022838770494832643) found that deleting sim logs saved him 30 GB.

```
~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator
```

Comment: This is at least a command to run after removing simulators as simulator configuration won't be deleted on the filesystem after deleting them in xcode

Comment: Before do this, remove unused Runtimes file here: `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes`. Then run your command (`xcrun simctl delete unavailable`), it will delete the simulators that we just deleted their runtime

Comment: You should also remove deleted simulators from the file ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/device_set.plist.

Comment: `xcrun simctl delete unavailable` returns `xcrun: error: unable to find utility "simctl", not a developer tool or in PATH` (macOS Catalina 10.15.7)

I've found all simulator related files in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms` and deleted the content of that directory

Answer (score 51):

Slightly off topic but could be very useful as it could be the basis for other tasks you might want to do with simulators.

I like to keep my simulator list to a minimum, and since there is no multi-select in the "Devices and Simulators" it is a pain to delete them all.

So I boot all the sims that I want to use then, remove all the simulators that I don't have booted.

Delete all the shutdown simulators:

```
xcrun simctl list | grep -w "Shutdown"  | grep -o "([-A-Z0-9]*)" | sed 's/[\(\)]//g' | xargs -I uuid xcrun simctl delete  uuid
```

If you need individual simulators back, just add them back to the list in "Devices and Simulators" with the plus button.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this - I had 286 simulators in the list - long overdue for a prune and deleting them one by one would have collapsed my brain to a singularity and thus ending all life on Earth. You saved me (us)!

Comment: Whew! Disaster averted!

Comment: Lifesaver!!! ❤️