# How to delete the iOS simulators in M1 mac

Tags: ios, apple-m1, simulator

I have a lot of simulators in my device and how can i delete those? Is it safe to delete?

xcrun simctl delete unavailable

**Path is like this and the below is the screenshot from my CCleaner**

/System/Volume/Data/Users/name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9F1DJWDJNDIUDHJDNIDBIDBDEDBn

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can remove them from /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes (Not ~/Library!):

[image]

check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30939453/how-to-uninstall-downloaded-xcode-simulator) for more